# Cloudflare redirection loop for PDF files

Tags: http, redirect, cloudflare

For some unknown reason, all PDFs on the site http://safetyaustraliagroup.com.au/, when clicked, result in a redirect loop and then ultimate failure:

e.g. http://safetyaustraliagroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Robert-Keft-Profile-2017.pdf

Result from Pingdom: [Pingdom Full Page Test Result](https://p5.zdusercontent.com/attachment/184946/rYuUCNbbWmWc8yc7LH59KblIj?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..bn6dtaP-1mldI1D-MoqxDQ.PGdr913ldfnVM3Cxlj0uaq9kNHKN2kfgskdCptEknQS0s6spmFBUdOx_4c0ZbRnje46-DFncjcgqgT_ezkvPZHu31y71gNOKC0Wz27VR_0pxFrmH41-ycilZ9syudkQj7jTocE518PTq1wA3Quif8-WBUVDzldYPHg2hC7074x4bs_eRi_k4WeSeR1EBTW9PAA5W6Fy9mfNyE8Tw_ktRBrOFjv5qdAlcUTytK4shJ0KwWT4RWNLApt7kZ8aDYU81WivoZTzuspqZvug5wsNvX76077F1dMPTPXeN9_DjNow.jRwucNvpZzHdmfrjg5iOvQ)

HOWEVER: If I bypass Cloudflare and add the IP address to my hosts file for the domain - it works as expected.

Cloudflare are not very helpful and say it's my problem but I can't understand what is causing this?  Especially when my testing indicates that it is only happening when connecting via Cloudflare.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. I think it is working now.

Comment: Do you have a ticket number from when you contacted Cloudflare support?